# PHP Preg_match match exact word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have stored as |1|7|11|
I need to use preg_match to check |7| is there or |11| is there etc, How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the faster [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) if you only need to check for the existence of two numbers.

```
if(strpos($mystring, '|7|') !== FALSE AND strpos($mystring, '|11|') !== FALSE)
{
    // Found them
}
```

Or using slower regex to capture the number

```
preg_match('/\|(7|11)\|/', $mystring, $match);
```

Use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test regexes for free.

Answer (score 30):

Use `\b` before and after the expression to match it as a whole word only:

```
$str1 = 'foo bar';       // has matches (foo, bar)
$str2 = 'barman foobar'; // no matches

$test1 = preg_match('/\b(foo|bar)\b/', $str1);
$test2 = preg_match('/\b(foo|bar)\b/', $str2);

var_dump($test1); // 1
var_dump($test2); // 0
```

So in your example, it would be:

```
$str1 = '|1|77|111|';  // has matches (1)
$str2 = '|01|77|111|'; // no matches

$test1 = preg_match('/\b(1|7|11)\b/', $str1);
$test2 = preg_match('/\b(1|7|11)\b/', $str2);

var_dump($test1); // 1
var_dump($test2); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `preg_match` (even though I recommend `strpos`, like on Xeoncross' answer), use this:

```
if (preg_match('/\|(7|11)\|/', $string))
{
    //found
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you can replace `(7|11)` for `(7|11|13)`, for example, to match a 7, 11, or 13.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string always starts and ends with an `|` :

```
strpos($string, '|'.$number.'|'));
```