# When does preg_match(): Unknown modifier error occur?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, exact-match

```
\\    $DigitalSignature have full name value passed
$SignatureMatch =  '/' . strtolower( $NameFirst . ' ' . $NameLast ) . '$/';
if( true == preg_match( $SignatureMatch, strtolower( $DigitalSignature ) ) )
{
    $boolIsValid = true;
}
```

I am having this code for exact matching first name and last name match with digital signature. But this gives error reported me in error log on production(live).

```
preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'b'
```

I am unable to reproduce this error. How can I get this error firstly. And how to resolve this error for exact matching.

I have seen many questions on SO but not getting when will get this error. And how do I resolve that. Some of questions out of many I have saw are -

1. [Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215947/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-unknown-modifier)
2. [Unknown modifier in preg_match() statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810951/unknown-modifier-in-preg-match-statement)
3. [Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215947/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-unknown-modifier)
4. [Unknown modifier 'l' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820753/unknown-modifier-l-error)
5. [Unknown modifier 'g' PHP regex error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292582/unknown-modifier-g-php-regex-error)
6. [Unknown modifier '/' in ...? what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565615/unknown-modifier-in-what-is-it)
7. [preg_match() Unknown modifier '[' help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011383/preg-match-unknown-modifier-help)
8. [Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'v'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321068/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-unknown-modifier-v)
9. [PHP Preg_match match exact word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305085/php-preg-match-match-exact-word)
10. [Unknown modifier 'v' when using preg_match() expression in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394323/unknown-modifier-v-when-using-preg-match-expression-in-regex)
11. [preg_match(); - Unknown modifier '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589807/preg-match-unknown-modifier)
12. [preg_match error Unknown modifier '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288674/preg-match-error-unknown-modifier)
13. [Unknown modifier '(' when using preg_match() with a REGEX expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153261/unknown-modifier-when-using-preg-match-with-a-regex-expression)

Comment: We'll need to see the resultant pattern rather than the vars that create it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first name or last name contains a `/`, your regex will look something like:

```
/john/doe$/
```

To `preg_match`, this looks like the regex is `/john/`, with the trailing `doe$/` being the modifiers. Those are of course invalid modifiers. You need to escape the regex delimiters (`/`) inside the regex itself using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote).

Answer (score 4):

`$NameFirst` or `$NameLast` may contain a slash /.

You should replace this

```
$SignatureMatch =  '/' . strtolower( $NameFirst . ' ' . $NameLast ) . '$/';
```

By this :

```
$SignatureMatch =  '/' . preg_quote(strtolower( $NameFirst . ' ' . $NameLast ), '/') . '$/';
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the strings you're inputting (`$NameFirst` or `$NameLast`) contains a `/`. Use a different delimiter or escape it in the strings.

Also, if you're only checking if a substring is inside a different string, don't use `preg_match`, use `stripos()` as it will be much faster.

```
if (stripos($DigitalSignature ,"$NameFirst $NameLast")) { /* It exists! */ }
```

Comment: I am removing slashes from $DigitalSignature before passing to check.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I didn't mean `$DigitalSignature`.

Comment: Thanks. I am finally able to reproduce this error. I require exact match. Is it possible with stripos?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: If you require an exact match, use the equality sign `==`. If you need to check that the signature contains the first and last names, use `stripos()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a regular expression in this case because you are not using any pattern matching.  If you just want to find one string inside of another, then use the `strpos` or `strrpos` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

If it's important that the name be found at the end of the signature, then it's even easier: Take a substring from $signature that is that many characters long from the end.

```
$fullname = strtolower( "$NameFirst $NameLast" );
$len = strlen($fullname);
$possible_name = substr( $fullname, -$len, $len );
$boolIsValid = ( $possible_name == $fullname );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx), the delimiters would be added for you automatically:

```
$SignatureMatch =  strtolower($NameFirst . ' ' . $NameLast) . '$';

if (pattern($SignatureMatch, 'i')->matches($DigitalSignature))
{
    $boolIsValid = true;
}
```